# script that will monitor changes in at least 2 files/directories and execute a third script only when both are modified

Tags: linux, bash

I have two sensors that each create an entry in a text file when triggered. Now I need something to monitor these two files (i can also put them in 2 directories each if that helps in any way) and trigger a third script only when changes occur to both of the aforementioned files/directories. I need real-time (or near to it) between events and notification. I have found tools like inotify-wait, fswatch, entr and some others but all of these are triggered at any change.

At the moment I'm trying this but it does not work properly:

```
#!/bin/bash
while inotifywait -e modify /home/user/triggerdir/ ;
do
  if [ "inotifywait -e modify /home/user/triggerdir2/" ];
    then
          echo Alert | mail -n -s "test-notify SCRIPT HUZAAAA" user@gmail.com
  else
    # Don't do anything unless we've found one of those
    :
  fi
done
```

I have looked for similar issues/solutions on the web, the closest would be [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/631954/inotifywait-with-counter-does-not-work) but it has no working answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're having trouble with that, you might consider a simplistic approach.

Rather than a loop, I'd put your script in the `crontab`. Run it every day, every hour, every minute, whatever you need. If you need more often, you *could* loop, but make sure you at least sleep a second to be nice to the CPU.

If a minute or more between event and notification is ok this should be all you need:

```
#!/bin/bash
key=/some/safe/path/.hidden_filename 
[[ -e "$key" ]] || touch "$key" # make sure it exists
if [[ file1 -nt "$key" && file2 -nt "$key" ]]; then 
  mail -n -s "test-notify SCRIPT HUZAAAA" user@gmail.com <<< "Alert!"
  touch "$key"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I have hacked something together which does work as I need it to though is terrible coding (probably shouldn't be called that)
3 scripts involved:
script 1:

```
#!/bin/bash
count=0
while :
do
    { inotifywait -e modify /home/user/triggerdir/ && let count="$count + 1"; } || exit 1
    if [ "$count" -eq "2" ]; then
        echo Alert | mail -n -s "Huzzah" user@gmail.com
        /home/user/trigger2.sh &&
        killall trigger.sh inotifywait
    fi
done
```

script 2:

```
#!/bin/bash
count=0
while :
do
    { inotifywait -e modify /home/user/triggerdir/ && let count="$count + 1"; } || exit 1
    if [ "$count" -eq "2" ]; then
        echo Alert | mail -n -s "Huzzah" user@gmail.com
        /home/user/trigger.sh &&
        killall trigger2.sh #Do something.
#        count=-250
    fi
done
```

as the two scripts spawn bash/inotify processes I run once in 24 hours a cronjob two kill those using this script 3:

```
#!/bin/bash
killall trigger2.sh trigger.sh inotifywait bash
```

any help to improve is welcome, thanks :)